# Non-reserved yet safe characters for delimiters in a URL

Tags: url, get

I have seen the following on StackOverflow about URL characters:

> There are two sets of characters you need to watch out for - Reserved and Unsafe.
>   The reserved characters are:
>
> - ampersand ("`&`")
> - dollar ("`$`")
> - plus sign ("`+`")
> - comma ("`,`")
> - forward slash ("`/`")
> - colon ("`:`")
> - semi-colon ("`;`")
> - equals ("`=`")
> - question mark ("`?`")
> - 'At' symbol ("`@`").

> The characters generally considered unsafe are:
>
> - space,
> - question mark ("`?`")
> - less than and greater than ("`<>`")
> - open and close brackets ("`[]`")
> - open and close braces ("`{}`")
> - pipe ("`|`")
> - backslash ("`\`")
> - caret ("`^`")
> - tilde ("`~`")
> - percent ("`%`")
> - pound ("`#`").

I'm trying to code a URL so I can parse it using delimiters. They can't be numbers or letters though. Does anyone have a list of characters that are NOT Reserved but ARE safe to use?

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: How exactly are you wanting to parse the URL?

Comment: How many "fields" are you expecting to have to separate by these delimiters?

Comment: Hi.. I have like 3 fields... so something like A473648444|42433^23422 where | and ^ are the delimiters ...then I would parse the string based on them

Answer (score 4):

Don't bother trying to use safe/unreserved characters. Just use whatever delimiters you want and URLencode the whole thing. Then URL decode it on the other end and parse normally.

Is there a reason you can't just use the standard delimiter for URL parameters (&)? That is the most straightforward way to do it instead of trying to roll your own.

For example the standard URL syntax already allows for multi-valued paramaters natively. This is perfectly legal and doesn't require any trickery.

```
Somepage.aspx?parameterName=A&parameterName=B
```

The result is that the page would be passed "A,B" in the parameterName attribute.

Comment: So I could use an unsafe character if it's encoded? I'm using .Net and will research how to do that?  Thanks!!

Comment: Yes, you should be able to put just about anything in a URL if you URLencode it. Look up Server.URLEncode.